# Can't export to .wrl after I have changed the pose.

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects, export

I am able to export as .wrl files, but if I have changed the pose of my object, this option is not clickable. How do I solve this problem. I have tried to "Set as rest position" and "Convert to mesh from surface". But it dosen't seems to unlock the export option. 
I am new to this program. 
Thanks you for helping :)
[image: The Picture]

Answer (score 1):

The vrml export addon only exports the active mesh object, if the active object is not a mesh object then the export option is disabled.

After using the armature to re-pose your object you need to re-select the mesh object to be able to export it.